# Unit Test Multiple Input/Output Test

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

I recently discovered GitHub Classroom.
I wanted to assign a homework to my students with auto-grading. The project is a Mad Libs Generator. I want to use *unittest* framework to auto grade my student's homework. Since it's a Mad Libs Generator it should take multiple inputs.
Please help me.

Sincerly,

A Programmer like you.

Comment: It might be useful to review https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help other devs to help you. (As a side note, I am not sure whether the unittest framework is even a good fit)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specific system, but I assume the mad-lib choices would be fixed in each test case. So, really, you have one fixed set of inputs for each test case, and you just check for the right output.